# passport.authenticate does not execute on a route

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I use Passport-jwt Strategy for authentication in express project,

here is mt passport-jwt config in this directory: /config/passport.js

```js
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt')
 .Strategy,
 ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt')
 .ExtractJwt;

var User = require(__dirname + '/../models/user');
var config = require(__dirname+ '/database');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    console.log("here: passport-jwt");
 var opts = {}
 opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
 opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
 passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
  User.findOne({
   id: jwt_payload.id
  }, function(err, user) {
   if (err) {
    return done(err, false);
   }
   if (user) {
    done(null, user);
   } else {
    done(null, false);
   }
  });
 }));
};
```

and in account route in /routes/account.js directory i call it this way:

```
var passport = require('passport');
require(__dirname + '/../config/passport')(passport);

router.post('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
session: false
}), function(req, res) { ... }
```

but the problem is passport function for authentication does not execute. and "here: passport-jwt" did not shown.

where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in app.js, routes must be declared like this:

after adding these lines:

```
var passport = require('passport');  
app.use(passport.initialize());
```

you should add these lines:

```
var account = require(__dirname + '/routes/account')(app, express, passport);
app.use('/account', account);
```

and in the route itself:

```
module.exports = function(app, express, passport) {

    var router = express.Router();

    router.post('/', function(req, res) {

        passport.authenticate('jwt', function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
                res.sendStatus(406);
            } else {
                if (!user) {
                    res.sendStatus(400);
                } else {...}
            }
       });
        }

    }
}
```

my mistake was that is put `console.log("here: passport-jwt");` in the first line of module, but in fact `passport.use(..)` part executing every time!

and the last thing was the `findOne` part in passport config, `passport.use(...)` part, when you want to use native id in MongoDB, you should query `_id` instead of `id`!

So, the correct code is:

```
User.findOne({
            _id: jwt_payload.id
        }, function(err, user) {
              ...
           });
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) { 
    passport.authenticate('jwt', 
       {
       session: false
       });
});
```

Comment: i tried this but the problem is still there.
and the method of route is post (maybe it is make difference).